# Updating rows in laravel mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've set up a database and want to update the column `status` for each row in my `UsersController`:

I started with this:

```
User::where('id', '=', 1)->update(['status' => $status]);
```

This is working, but I need some loop to change all the rows, something like this:

1. foreach $id from the table
2. run some code to change individual $status variable
3. set individual $status value in the 'status' column in each row:

   ```
   User::where('id', '=', $id)->update(['status' => $status])
   ```
4. end foreach

So for me its unclear how to go through the table via the foreach. Then save the calculated status from my code to each individual id?

Answer (score 3):

@Serge solution is fine for few records but you should be able to use chuck as @ceejayoz suggested

```
User::chunk(100, function ($users) {
    $users->each(function ($user) {
        $user->status = getStatus($user);
        $user->save();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless the table contains millions of rows... a simple procedural way of doing it is...

```
$users = Users::get(); // Gets a collection of all users...
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    //compute your status
    $user->status = get_your_user_status($user->id);
    $user->save();
}
```

You could also consider using a more functional approach with map for example...

Comment: If the table *does* contain millions of rows, look into the `chunk` function.